# How & Why Do Sites Differ With Their URL Handling?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I notice that many sites, even well-established ones, differ on the way they handle URLS.

```
Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url+php
Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=url+handling
Facebook: http://www.facebook.com/userID
Normal PHP: http://example.com/page.php?param=1&other=2
```

Wordpress can change between different URL structures with ease.

My first question is simple: How do you go about changing the way your site handles a URL? I think you have to setup some sort `htaccess` rewrite, but I am not sure.

Also, on sites that use `/` to pass parameters, how do these sites access a certain folder? I normally use http://example.com/includes to access my `includes` folder, but if I am using `/` to pass parameters, how would my site know what I am trying to do?

My second question is much more important: Why do sites change their URL structures? What's the rationale behind it? Is it just to be unique? What about performance...which one is the lightest on the server? Or is their no real difference and companies just think a certain structure looks nicer in the Browser URL Bar?

Comment: How to rewrite URLs: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite. This is useful for SEO because search engines theoretically don't index GET parameters.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that all of these sites are running PHP.  This question is far too vague and asking for far too much discussion, but the URL mapping is roughly analogous to the definition of an API.  A lot of different factors could affect what is perceived to be optimal: but clear definition of the interface being the only practically important part in the end.

Comment: Didn't mean to sound that way, I realize there are a variety of other platforms that a server could be running. I am simply most familiar with PHP so I used my PHP understanding to show what I was trying to ask.

Comment: In practice you should likely go with what you are most comfortable with, and you should ask more specific practical questions as you have them.  If you're looking for ideology you should look up things like Clean URLs and constructing RESTful APIs.  A good place to start is to try to really understand how URLs themselves can be leveraged: http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html.  And don't worry about performance without first profiling for bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To more thoroughly address your question I'd like to direct your attention away from the web server momentarily and towards the HTTP protocol and how it fundamentally works.

HTTP is a very simple protocol that comprises of a REQUEST-RESPONSE model. The client (*the user's browser basically*) sends what is called an HTTP request header that may or may not also have a non-empty HTTP request body. The header looks something like this when you want to visit a URL like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url+php

```
GET /questions/tagged/url+php HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

Notice that on line 1 of the HTTP request header your browser formulates in order to send to the stackoverflow server the entire line is made up of 3 very simple parts.

1. The **request verb**, which is usually something like GET or POST (but can be many other things as well). This tells the server how you want to treat the request so that it expects it to respond.
2. The **request path**, which can be made up of any path the host is willing to accept plus any optional query string the client wishes to provide and is usually required to be *URL-encoded*.
3. The **protocol version** the request was made in. This is usually either HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/1.0.

The second line of this request supplies the server with the host name the client intends to  reach with this request.

Now, on the server side once your web server receives this actual request it can chose to deal with that request however it pleases. However, the behavior you are probably very used to in any common apache/nginx/lighttpd web server setup is that the path supplied by the client must match a physical path in your **document root** directory. This is far from the truth. This is only one way in which your web server can handle the request. You can chose to tell your web server to handle each request in a different way.

As an example Apache's httpd web server offers mod_rewrite which can tell your web server to rewrite request URIs so that the server can redirect them somewhere else based on specific rules such as regular expressions or given set of conditions.

```
   <Directory />
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </Directory>
```

The above is a very simple example of what WordPress's rewrite rule looks like that they usually supply you with an in .htaccess file, except I took this from my virtualhost file instead, which is usually much faster than using .htaccess. Always consider putting anything you want to put in .htaccess into your apache.conf's vhost `Directory` directive first before you decide to go with .htaccess since they are runtime files and thus by nature slower. Generally speaking mod_rewrite itself is just slow and should only ever be used as a last resort.

In any case all this rewrite stuff does is redirect any request that comes in to your webserver on the root directory of that vhosts' `DocumentRoot` to be redirected to your index.php file which then handles the request internally to determine which PHP scripts it should include for this request and how the page will be rendered.

This is just the poor-man's way of doing it. It's normally referred to as a *front-controller* or *front-router*. It just acts as a middle-man between the request URI and the actuall way in which we will handle rendering a response for any given request URI.

If you were stackoverflow or google you would have reverse proxies (*load balancers basically*) that deal with these requests at a much higher level and reach out to other servers in the datacenter that will then handle the rendering of the request based on that request URI.

Remember all we did was take the `GET /questions/tagged/url+php HTTP/1.1` part of the client's **HTTP Request Header** and send it to another script or program that knows how to respond to it. Just like your web server can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, some folders in your website are not shown to users. Example some media files. You will do this in your `.htaccess` file

Below code will hide the directory listing.  If user points the browsers to a directory which does not have index file then in this case 403 error will be

```
Options -Indexes
```

If you want to show the directory use

```
Options +Indexes
```

See this link http://viralpatel.net/blogs/htaccess-directory-listing-enable-disable-allow-deny-prevent-htaccess-directory-listing/

For second question - Normally why people are using URL Rewrite is because of `SEO` friendly URL.

While searching it comes on front..

Example, you are having product details page, and you are passing product ID in the query string. Rewrite will change query string to proper URL with slash. This is very helpful for google to find the search result.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?product=$1&price=$2
```

Below links will help you.

http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html